# How to initialize string in a array to find its indexOf

Tags: java, android

I have made an application that recognizes if the same particular word has been pressed,
I have stored the words in the string array

```
String[] strAr = {"hallow,world,thanks"};
```

I am using indexOf method to detect whether the declared  words are typed from the string of words typed by the user
I have used the following code to do that but it doesn't toast the message

```
if ( string.toLowerCase().indexOf(String.valueOf(strAr)) != -1  ) {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi new world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want an array with a single element containing all the words separated by a comma and not a three-elements array instead? As in `String[] strArr = {"hallow", "world", "thanks"};`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but in Java that syntax would give you only one element.

The correct syntax should be `String[] strAt ={"hallow", "World", "thanks"};`

This way you have an array of 3 strings.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you will get `string` values by the interaction of the user.

In this case, you should use `ArrayList` instead of an `Array`. Because, your list size will be increased by time. If you use `ArrayList`, you won't need to worry about the size.

So, firstly you should create a global variable in your class:

```java
private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList();
```

Then, you can create a function which will do all the necessary things.

In the below code, firstly, you can check if your `ArrayList` contains the string you will be checking. If `ArrayList` doesn't have this `String`, that means this is a new word. You can add this word to your `ArrayList` and show a `Toast message` to notify the user about this is a new word.

```java
private void addStringToList(String string) {
    if (!strings.contains(string)) {
        strings.add(string);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi new world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```